# recaptcha response not submitting

Tags: php, recaptcha

Hello everyone this is my first time implementing a captcha any help is appreciated. My dilemma is that my submit button is frozen after solving the captcha. After some troubleshooting, I conclude that response is not submitting, `var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])` shows NULL however upon testing my code to a simple form insert without any design and database logic the captcha works. I suspect it has something to do with my forms design because it has multiple `div` tags I am not sure. I read somewhere that it affects the `div` inheritance. Here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $secretKey = "";
    $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    if($response->success)
    {
        echo "Your captcha finally works!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "HINDI PARIN GUMAGANA";
    }
}
?>
```

IF it helps my form has fifteen fields all are inside a `div` tag. Any help is appreciated Thank you.

```
<form method="post">
<div><input></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>
<button type="submit" name="submit">register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have, the actual code is too long so I put a representation instead.

Comment: recaptca v2 or v3  ?

Comment: it is for ReCaptcha v2

Answer (score 0):

This is for recaptcha v2 it should work fine with your form no meter how many inputs you have.
actualy your code looks fine is well.

```
<form method="POST">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) { 

        $secretKey   = "your_site_key";
        $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $userIP      = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url         = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
        $response    = file_get_contents($url);
        $response    = json_decode($response);

        if($response->success){
            echo "Verification success.";
        } else {
            echo "Verification failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My captcha is working now, I paste the <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div> after the submit button before it was above the submit button.

Comment: @JohnMacasinag interesting! it should not make difference as long as its between `<form>` tags, given code in answer works perfectly when I try on a live demo site.